# Azure (PowerShell) How to add an additional IP to multiple existent Network Security Groups (Source Address Prefix field)?

Tags: azure, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell

I need some help to add an extra IP (122.21.20.3/12) to a bunch of NSG in Azure. This is to allow an additional Source Address.
I was able to put together a script to help me find impacted NSGs. I have to add the new IP only to the NSGs containing another similar IP (122.21.20.2/12):

```
$azSubs = Get-AzSubscription

foreach ( $azSub in $azSubs ) {
    Set-AzContext -Subscription $azSub | Out-Null

    $azNsgs = Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup 
    
    foreach ( $azNsg in $azNsgs ) {
        Get-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -NetworkSecurityGroup $azNsg | Where-Object { $_.SourceAddressPrefix -eq '122.21.20.2/12' } | `
            Select-Object @{label = 'NSG Name'; expression = { $azNsg.Name } }, 
                          @{label = 'Rule Name'; expression = { $_.Name } },
                          @{label = 'Source IP'; expression = { $_.SourceAddressPrefix } },
                          @{label = 'Port Range'; expression = { $_.DestinationPortRange } }, Access, Priority, Direction, `
                          @{label = 'Resource Group Name'; expression = { $azNsg.ResourceGroupName } } 
      
    }    
}
```

I am able to get the list of affected NSGs. Not sure how to fit this into the SourceAddressPrefix for each of them.
Is **Set-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig** used for that? Does anyone have an example, please?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the above requirement , we have created the below PowerShell script which will pull all the existing Network Security Groups & their respective NSG rules.

We have added a condition in the below script to pull only the NSG rule that has SourceAddressPrefix with `ParticularIP` that we want & it will updated the NSG rule with Required `SourceIPAddressPrefixes`

**Here is the PowerShell Script :**

```html
connect-azaccount

$requiredIp=("10.x.x.x/27") ##Ip that you want to check 

$ngs=Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup ##list all Network Security Groups in the subscription

foreach($ng in $ngs){
    $nsgrule=$ng.SecurityRules ##appending the nsg rules of that particular Network Security Groups

foreach( $item in $nsgrule) {
    $ruleip=$item| Select-Object -Property SourceAddressPrefix,name ##pulling the sourceIPAddressPrefix of that existing NSG rule
       
foreach( $ip in $ruleip)
    {
        if( $ip.SourceAddressPrefix -eq $requiredIp){
        
        $rec=Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $ng.Name

        ## add the required IP in the "-SourceAddressPrefix" flag in the below cmdlet to update the NSG rule with the required IP address

        Set-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name $ip.Name -NetworkSecurityGroup $rec -SourceAddressPrefix ($($requiredIp),"10.x.x.x/27") -Protocol Tcp -Access Allow -Direction Inbound -DestinationAddressPrefix * -SourcePortRange * -DestinationPortRange * -Priority 310
        Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -NetworkSecurityGroup $rec
    }
   }
}
}
```

**Here is the Sample Output for reference:**

[image]

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! Is it possible to keep "Priority" parameter as it was?

Comment: Yes, you can use the same priority it will overwrite the existing NSG rule.

Comment: That would be difficult. There are hundreds of NSGs, with different priority. Is there any way to force a wildcard parameter for Priority? Any idea?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you asking about keeping the priority as a condition in the above script or are you talking about using priority flag in ``set-aznetworksecurityruleconfig`` cmdlet ?

Comment: I would like to keep the Priority of affected rules, somehow. 
I see the Priority parameter of Set-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig is mandatory and don't accept wildcard. Do you have any idea?

Comment: As per the `Set-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/set-aznetworksecurityruleconfig?view=azps-7.0.0) `priority` flag is not manadatory. you can use ``$item.Priority`` instead of passing priority value to the cmdlet to update the existing nsg rule.


if you dont pass the priority flag the script is failing stating with below error 

Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup : Security rule has invalid Priority. Value provided: 0 Allowed range 100-4096.
StatusCode: 400

Comment: Works like a charm!
Following the same logic, If I would like to increment the IP list with the new value, would it be like?

-SourceAddressPrefix ($($ip.SourceAddressPrefix),"172.21.0.0/17")

Otherwise, it is keeping only the 2 IPs (requiredIp and the new one). Please advise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240008/discussion-between-venkateshdodda-mt-and-rookieroo).

Comment: you can add them  -SourceAddressPrefix ($($ip.SourceAddressPrefix,"172.21.0.0./17","172.x.x.x/17","172.x.x.x/17",..) in this Manner

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Comment: I see a huge problem with this script:
It is not possible to append a new IP to the existent SourceAddressPrefix list. You are only allowed to add IP addresses individually.
If they are added like this, it is not allowed:

-SourceAddressPrefix ($($item.SourceAddressPrefix),"172.23.0.0/17")
Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'SourceAddressPrefix'. Specified method is not supported.

Comment: I am able to add multiple source address prefix using the same above script here is [reference image](https://i.imgur.com/0UyuDju.png) Update the same in discussion chat as well

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you need to change your NSG.

Something like that, maybe?

```
$NSG = Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -Name 'MyNSG' -ResourceGroupName 'MyRG'

$Params = @{
  'Name'                     = 'NewRule'
  'NetworkSecurityGroup'     = $NSG
  'Protocol'                 = '*'
  'Direction'                = 'Outbound'
  'Priority'                 = 200
  'SourceAddressPrefix'      = '*'
  'SourcePortRange'          = '*'
  'DestinationAddressPrefix' = '*'
  'DestinationPortRange'     = @('80', '443')
  'Access'                   = 'Deny'
}

Add-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig @Params | Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup
```

Answer (score 1):

The complete script to perform this task is:

```
connect-azaccount

$requiredIp=("10.x.x.x/27") ##Ip that you want to check 

$ngs=Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup ##list all Network Security Groups in the subscription

foreach($ng in $ngs){
    $nsgrule=$ng.SecurityRules ##appending the nsg rules of that particular Network Security Groups

foreach( $item in $nsgrule) {
    $ruleip=$item| Select-Object -Property SourceAddressPrefix,name ##pulling the sourceIPAddressPrefix of that existing NSG rule
       
foreach( $ip in $ruleip)
    {
        if( $ip.SourceAddressPrefix -eq $requiredIp){
        
        $rec=Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $ng.Name

        ## add the required IP in the "-SourceAddressPrefix" flag in the below cmdlet to update the NSG rule with the required IP address

        Set-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig `
            -Name $ip.Name `
            -NetworkSecurityGroup $rec `
            -SourceAddressPrefix ( @($item.SourceAddressPrefix) + $newIP ) `
            -Protocol * `
            -Access Allow `
            -Direction Inbound `
            -DestinationAddressPrefix * `
            -SourcePortRange * `
            -DestinationPortRange * `
            -Priority $item.Priority
        Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -NetworkSecurityGroup $rec
    }
   }
}
}
```